# ffmpeg getting Invalid UE golomb code when saving udp multicast to file

Tags: ffmpeg, udp, multicast

I am using ffmpeg to capture a UDP multicast stream and save it to a file but I'm having an issue with an "Invalid UE golomb code"

Command:

```
ffmpeg -i "udp://238.0.0.1:1234" -c copy -f segment -segment_time 900 -segment_atclocktime 1 -reset_timestamps 1 -strftime 1 $datestamp.mp4 -report
```

This works fine for around 3-5 minutes and then freezes without an errors or indication why, the only thing I think it could be is the following error is spammed in the log file;

```
Invalid UE golomb code-1.0 size=N/A time=00:00:09.97 bitrate=N/A
```

The only other thing I can see is the following in the log file;

```
unknown SEI type 229
```

If someone could point help me out here that would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

after upgrading my ffmpeg version, this fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

This could be because you are in udp force your streaming to tcp